# Rendering React Components from String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I'm trying to create multiple React components dynamically from a string entered by the user. Each letter is supposed to be rendered as a separate component.

My plan was to create an array from the string and map over it returning each component in a new array.

My main issue is to convert the letter (string) into the component's name.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'

import A from './ComponentA'
import B from './ComponentB'
import C from './ComponentC'

const userInput = "ABC"
const userInputArray = userInput.split("")

const components = userInputArray.map((comp, index) => {
  return (
    React.createElement(eval(comp), { key: [index]})
  )
})

function App() {

  return (
    <>
    { components }
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

I thought I found a solution using 'eval' but it fails when minified in production.

(*Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.*)

Comment: You have a string and want an associated value - why not use an object?

Comment: I think you should create a function with `switch` statement that will return the needed component for each letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no reason to use `eval()` at all: you can simply use a dictionary to store your component references, and then render it accordingly.

Note that I have used `i` as a key, but you really should not use it but instead rely on a stable, unique identifier.

```
import A from "./ComponentA";
import B from "./ComponentB";
import C from "./ComponentC";

// NOTE: Added 'D' to test for component that doesn't exist
const userInput = "ABCD";
const userInputArray = userInput.split("");

const components = { A, B, C };

export default function App() {
  return userInputArray.map((component, i) => {
    const Component = components[component];
    if (!Component) return <></>;

    return <Component key={i} />;
  });
}
```

[image: Edit Dynamic components]

However, what I would recommend is that you take advantage of React lazy loading and suspense feature, so that you don't have to load all components at once if the user input array does not need all of them. It is little more advanced, but here is another proof-of-concept example:

- It allows you to input dynamic string that is parsed to load in the necessary components
- It uses React.Suspense + React.lazy to perform dynamic loading

```
import { lazy, Suspense, useState } from "react";

const components = {
  A: lazy(() => import("./ComponentA")),
  B: lazy(() => import("./ComponentB")),
  C: lazy(() => import("./ComponentC"))
};

export default function App() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("ABCD");
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={userInput}
        onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value)}
      />
      <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
        {userInput.split("").map((component, i) => {
          const Component = components[component.toUpperCase()];
          if (!Component) return <></>;

          return <Component key={i} />;
        })}
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Dynamic components with lazy loading]